# How to set app icon for Electron / Atom Shell App

Tags: icons, electron

How do you set the app icon for your Electron app?

I am trying `BrowserWindow({icon:'path/to/image.png'});` but it does not work.

Do I need to pack the app to see the effect?

Comment: You can follow https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/66

Comment: One thing you can do for Mac is put a `postinstall` script in your project that will copy the .icns file in place under node_modules/ automatically.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Setting the `icon` property when creating the `BrowserWindow` only has an effect on Windows and Linux.

To set the icon on OS X, you can use [electron-packager](https://github.com/maxogden/electron-packager) and set the icon using the `--icon` switch.

It will need to be in .icns format for OS X. There is an [online icon converter](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns) which can create this file from your .png.

Comment: Can you fix this answer to be accurate wrt Windows please?

Comment: Thanks @ShawnRakowski, you're right - I've just tested this and the icon property does indeed work on Windows too. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This worked at first, but then I sent the distributable app to my friend and it didnt work! Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing how to do this. I tried `electron-package . --all --icon` but got an error "TypeError: Path must be a string. Received true"

Comment: @Nick you will need to do something like the following `electron-packager . YourApplicationName --all --icon "path/to/my/icon.ico"`

Comment: I agree with Tieme.  The answer's linked icon converter is old and only supports icon sizes of 256x256, which is ok for Windows and Linux, but Mac OS .icns files max out at 1024x1024.  @AlexWarren, please update your answer to reflect this.

Comment: With electron-packager you'll want to do something like "--icon=src/assets/icons/logo" and electron will handle adding the extension for the relevant platform

Comment: The solution by @PedroPovedaQ works (I checked the source code and you don't need to specify the extension), but I'm forced to call a `touch builddir/myapp.app` to see the icon in my Finder. Seems like MacOS need help to see the new icon.
See https://gist.github.com/fabiofl/5873100#gistcomment-1320553

Comment: Have you ever had an issue where the app icon looks fine but the icon that shows up within the notification looks bad, almost like when a TV goes bad...

Comment: On Windows, I'm using ` BrowserWindow({icon: './icon.png'}) ` and it works when using ` npm start ` on terminal.  When the window pops up, it has the customized tiny icon on top of the window. But the problem is that it only works while testing using ` npm start ` so when I package my app into an ` .exe ` file, The app no longer has the icon in the explorer nor on top of its window when opened.

Answer (score 96):

Below is the solution that I have :

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  icon: __dirname + '/Bluetooth.ico',
})
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that __dirname is the path of your /src/ folder (i.e. the folder of your app.js/main.js file).

Comment: `.icns` not needed ?

Comment: how to create .ico file, is there any online tool?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot search on google "online ico creator" there are plenty of ico creater.

Comment: IntelliJ suggested that is better to write: `icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icons/png/256x256.png')`

Comment: this solution seems not working on macOs.

Answer (score 35):

**For Electron < 3.0 version**. Updated **package.json:**

```
"build": {
  "appId": "com.my-website.my-app",
  "productName": "MyApp",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 ${author}",
  "mac": {
    "icon": "./public/icons/mac/icon.icns",     <---------- set Mac Icons
    "category": "public.app-category.utilities"
  },
  "win": {
    "icon": "./public/icons/png/256x256.png" <---------- set Win Icon
  },
  "files": [
    "./build/**/*",
    "./dist/**/*",
    "./node_modules/**/*",
    "./public/**/*",       <---------- need for get access to icons
    "*.js"
  ],
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "public" <---------- folder where placed icons
  }
},
```

After build application you can see icons. This solution don't show icons in developer mode.
I don't setup icons in `new BrowserWindow()`.

Comment: 'build' in the application package.json is not supported since 3.0 anymore

Answer (score 22):

**

### IMPORTANT:
OUTDATED ANSWER, LOOK AT THE OTHER NEWER SOLUTIONS

**

You can do it for macOS, too. Ok, not through code, but with some simple steps:

1. Find the .icns file you want to use, open it and copy it via Edit menu
2. Find the electron.app, usually in node_modules/electron/dist
3. Open the information window
4. Select the icon on the top left corner (gray border around it)
5. Paste the icon via cmd+v
6. Enjoy your icon during development :-)

[image]

Actually it is a general thing not specific to electron. You can change the icon of many macOS apps like this.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for this. I did need to drag and drop to get it to work but amazing nonetheless.

Comment: Complete instructions: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25383?locale=en_US

Comment: This seems to only work for development.  When I run 'yarn dist', the icns file gets replaced with the default electron one.

Comment: @Dave Actually he said `6. Enjoy your icon during *development* :-)`

Comment: Well guys... I know... But this fix is over 2 years old... ;-) And btw. you should be able to use this "hack" also on a final build, since you simply change it on the dist app... Have not tried for a while.. And who knows maybe there is an official way, now... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to update the app icon in the taskbar, then Update following in main.js (if using typescript then main.ts)

```
win.setIcon(path.join(__dirname, '/src/assets/logo-small.png'));
```

`__dirname` points to the root directory (same directory as `package.json`) of your application.

Comment: sure about mac?

Comment: This works for windows but not Mac

Answer (score 4):

In case you're converting an existing web app to an Electron app, you can use the following code:

```js
const path = require('path')

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  icon: path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico'),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I don't need to specify any path such as `./`, since I use `build` directory, and this is my configuration:

```
"build": {
  "directories":{
     "output": "build"
  },
  "mac": {
     "icon": "build/logo.icns"
  },
  "win": {
     "icon": "build/logo.png"
   }
}
```

I found that using `./logo.png` will make electron shows the same error:

`default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set`

Answer (score 1):

## electron-packager

---

Setting the icon property when creating the `BrowserWindow` only has an effect on Windows and Linux platforms. you have to package the .icns for max

To set the icon on OS X using `electron-packager`, set the icon using the --icon switch.

It will need to be in .icns format for OS X. There is an online icon converter which can create this file from your .png.

## electron-builder

---

As a most recent solution, I found an alternative of using `--icon` switch. Here is what you can do.

1. Create a directory named `build` in your project directory and put the `.icns` the icon in the directory as named `icon.icns`.
2. run builder by executing command `electron-builder --dir`.

You will find your application icon will be automatically picked up from that directory location and used for an application while packaging.

> **Note**: The given answer is for recent version of `electron-builder` and tested with electron-builder v21.2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 1000,icon: __dirname + '/logo.png'}); //*.png or *.ico will also work
```

in my case it worked !

Answer (score 1):

## windows 10

### electron-packager

```
electron-packager . appname--platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite --icon=icons/icon.ico --out=release-builds
```

the icon keeps getting cached, so using the --out flag helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the examples for icon file path tend to assume that main.js is under the base directory. If the file  is not in the base directory of the app, the path specification must account for that fact.

For example, if the main.js is under the src/ subdirectory, and the icon is under assets/icons/, this icon path specification will work:

```
icon: __dirname + "../assets/icons/icon.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can search icon.png in the project directory and change both files(one for Debian and one for Redhat) with your custom icon(with the same name).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `electron-builder`, you can follow [their documentation](https://www.electron.build/icons.html) on how to add your app-icon.

You can specify a path to set the icon in the `electron-builder.json5` configuration file, e.g. for mac:

```
/**
 * @see https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration
 */
{
appId: 'YourAppId',
mac: {
  artifactName: '${productName}_${version}.${ext}',
  target: ['dmg'],
  icon: 'public/logo.png',
 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use **.ico extension** for app icon. You can refer the piece of code which is mentioned below. If suppose you having any other image formats, Just convert it with .ico extension using online converters

```
let mainWindow;
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1200,
        height:600,
        icon: path.join(__dirname,'/icon.ico'),
    });
```

- Here _dirname refers to your file path.
- icon.ico - Image file

Answer (score -5):

**For windows use Resource Hacker**

Download and Install: :D

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

- Run It
- Select open and select exe file
- On your left open a folder called **Icon Group**
- Right click **1: 1033**
- Click replace icon
- Select the icon of your choice
- Then select replace icon
- Save then close

**You should have build the app**