# Electron (Atom Shell) app icon

Tags: electron

I'm trying to set an electron icon for my app. I try this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1280, height: 768, icon: __dirname + "/logo.ico" });
```

But it doesn't works for me. I read in others questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/setting-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app)) that setting the icon property when creating the BrowserWindow only has an effect on Windows and Linux. But I'm currently on Linux, not in Mac OS.

How can I deal with this? Must the icon have a fixed size or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: facing the same issue. have you find any answer to the question

Comment: Finally I got through Electron packager with --icon option. The icon can not have size 128x128px, and must have .ico format. So it worked for me. E.g: electron-packager . appName --platform=win32 --arch=all --icon='/path/logo.ico' --asar=true --prune --overwrite

Comment: size less than or greater than 128x128px supported?

Answer (score 2):

I just chased this question around for half an hour. What worked for me (running on windows), was I had to modify my path. Working in electron, I was too used to loading URLs, (`win.loadURL(dirName/index.html`)). So, when I went to put in my icon, I made the mistake of using `file://dirName/index`. It will NOT accept your image if you begin with `file://`. So, just write your path, e.g. `C://Users/etc/icon.png`. I don't know that this fixes all cases of this problem, but it was what was causing my image not to show.