# How to create file using NodeJs with custom file icon ? Or I want to set overlay icon while creating file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I develop application in NodeJs. I want to make overlay icon of file when create. (Windows and Mac) but I can't found any way using NodeJS while creating file.
So I think if file icon change when create file that is also acceptable.

Comment: why the electron tag?

Comment: Create what file? How? Show the icon where? You mean set the icon the WM uses?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I want exact implementation like https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/4878ad59-6cc0-4c6c-8efd-4cf723021b30.png @JaredSmith

Comment: [Possble duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894288/electron-cant-get-custom-icon-to-appear)

Comment: @JaredSmith No buddy, I want to set overlay icon on file (like TXT,PPT or Folder) not app icon above link is about change icon of electron app.

Comment: found any solution for this question?