# display a favicon in the head tag using electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, create-react-app

i have tried to add an Image inside the head Tag under /public like this .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> mytitle </title>
            <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" sizes="32*32" type="image/ico">


    </head>
</html>
```

but what im seeing is just mytitle.
[image]

Is there a way to show an Image next to the title using electron

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set app icon for Electron / Atom Shell App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no i need an icon in the Head Tag after starting the electron app and not to change the electron app icon

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think that the solution should be like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page but that doesnt work for electron