# Can’t set icon besides `BrowserWindow`’s `title` in Electron like `favicon` is seen in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, electron

I need to set an icon beside the `title` of `BrowserWindow` like `favicon` is seen in Chrome.

It doesn’t work even if I put it in HTML.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I tried doing the following as well:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
 width: 1200,
 height: 800,
 icon: path.resolve(__dirname, ‘favicon.ico’)
})
```

But it doesn’t work. Is it actually possible?

> Note: I am not talking about the app icon. I want an icon beside the title which is beside the traffic lights. For example, if you open **VSCode** for the 1st time you see **Welcome** at the top as shown in the image below. I want an icon besides **Welcome**

[image: vscode welcome]

Comment: you are using macOS, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31538436/6771708

Comment: @namila007 i think that gives the icon to the app. i want it besides **Welcome** as specified in the question

Comment: using the `icon:` it set the application icon on the specific window

Comment: @namila007 i'll try it when i get my Mac working. charger is dead & thanks to covid-19 i cant test it right now. currently on Windows, is the solution the same for Windows?

Comment: Ah i tried setting the icon on windows, it changes the icon of browserwindow. :)

Comment: On macos you need to set icons using `.icns` format ,`ico` format wont work on the macOS

Comment: @namila007 i think the same thing happens on macos as well. trust me i've tried it many times using `.icns` format only. hence the question. i don't think there's a way to do it. atleast not yet.

Comment: yes as i read, this can only set browserWindow icon, cant set another icon next to window title

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
new BrowserWindow({"frame":false})
```

and make bar with css codes

Comment: yep that's one way to do it. i've done that earlier too. i was wishing there must be a simpler way to do something like that though :)