# How do I set a window icon to a Buffer image in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, icons

I have an image that is stored in a buffer. I'm trying to set it as the window icon, but I can't find a way to do so. There is no path to the image, so I can't just use `win.setIcon('path/to/image')`.

I tried to do the following, to no success.

```
win.setIcon(buffer); // giving the buffer by itself
win.setIcon(buffer.toString('base64')); // giving the buffer as base64
win.setIcon(`data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString('base64')}`); // giving as base64 url

let imageObject = new Image();
imageObject.src = `data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString('base64')}`;
win.setIcon(imageObject); // giving image object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set app icon for Electron / Atom Shell App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app)

Comment: @RandyCasburn, this is not a duplicate as OP's trying to set the image from a buffer and neither via a file nor via an app package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Electron's documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winseticonicon-windows-linux), `BrowserWindow.setIcon ()` takes either a string or a `NativeImage`, a data type provided by Electron. You can convert your buffer to a `NativeImage` by using the following code:

```js
const { nativeImage } = require ("electron");

win.setIcon (nativeImage.createFromBuffer (buffer));
```

If that does not help, you can also pass your buffer as a Base 64 string in a data URL (like you have tried before) to the function `createFromDataURL`. For more information, see the [documentation on `NativeImage`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#nativeimagecreatefrombufferbuffer-options). It is also worth noting that you can pass advanced options to the `createFromBuffer` function to give Electron more hints about how to display your icon.