# Windows: Electron notifications not showing the app logo but everywhere else it does

Tags: electron, electron-builder

The app logo is properly shown everywhere else but in the notification section where it displays an empty logo

[image]

I know that you can add a custom image for the notification passing a `icon` property like so:

```
           new Notification({
              title: 'Test Notification',
              body: 'This is a test notification',
              icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.ico'),
            });
```

But that's not the logo I want to change.

The app when built also shows the correct logo elsewhere:

[image]

I also added an `icon` property when creating the `BrowserWindow` like advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app).

```
  const win = splashWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 320,
    height: 320,
    // more 
    icon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'icon.ico'),
  });
```

Adding a

```
win.setIcon(path.resolve(__dirname, 'icon.ico');
```

doesn't work too.

This code is all in `main.js`.

And I've been checking [the docs for the `App` class](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetfileiconpath-options) and there's a `getFileIcon` but it doesn't appear to be related to this.

*May be related?*

I have been able to modify the app name to 'Awesome App' via `setAppUserModelId` like so:

```
ipcMain.on('app-ready', () => {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    // somehow also change logo here? can't find it in the docs
    app.setAppUserModelId('Awesome app');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I call `app.setAppUserModelId('xxxx')` before `new Notification` and it works.

xxxx is your bundle id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do this right before launching any `BrowserWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    i have used below changes.
inside package.json --> add below. make sure to add  "appId": "YOUR APP NAME"
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "logo256.ico",
      "appId": "YOUR APP NAME"
    }


also make sure to add 
app.on("ready", ev => {
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    app.setAppUserModelId('YOUR APP NAME');
  }
}
```