# Electron.Net icon not used

Tags: icons, electron-builder, electron.net

I tried [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app) to set my custom icon for Electron.Net application (it is a Blazor application). I tried pretty much any absolute path / relative path combination I could think of, nothing helped...

For some reason, the icon (both in main window as in Task bar) keeps using the default icon... I tried pretty much any configuration but nothing seems to help... Maybe it is my `MyIcon.ico` icon that is at fault here? Does it need to be of specific resolution, or anythig?

Strange is - the splash image is showing... What am I doing wrong here?! (ps: for now I am only trying to build electron for Windows)

Here my electron.manifest:

```
{
    "executable": "MyFirstApp",
    "splashscreen": {
        "imageFile": "/wwwroot/Images/MySplash.png"
    },
    "name": "MyApp",
    "author": "Me",
    "singleInstance": false,
    "environment": "Production",
    "build": {    
        "appId": "com.MaApp.app",
        "productName": "MyApp",
        "copyright": "Copyright © 2020",
        "buildVersion": "1.0.18",
        "win": {
            "icon": "wwwroot/Images/MyIcon.ico"
        },
        "compression": "maximum",
        "directories": {
            "output": "../../../bin/Desktop"
        },
        "extraResources": [
            {
                "from": "./bin",
                "to": "bin",
                "filter": [ "**/*" ]
            }
        ],
        "files": [
            {
                "from": "./ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
                "to": "ElectronHostHook/node_modules",
                "filter": [ "**/*" ]
            },
            "**/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was RELATIVE path should be used from the compilation output directory, as [stated here](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/292#issuecomment-963646781).

Answer (score 0):

Commenting to say make sure your copy to output directory is set correctly in Visual Studio if you are putting the icon in a different folder like Assets.

I have my path set like so
 `"win": { "icon": "bin/Assets/icon.png"  },`