# How can I set the application logo with Electron-Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

My file structure looks like this:

[image: My file structure]

The *main.ts* file:

```typescript
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 725,
    minHeight: 725,
    width: 1200,
    minWidth: 1200,
    icon: 'C://Users//Admin//Desktop//VueElectronTest-master//src//main//logo.ico',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: '#000000',
      symbolColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    }
  });
```

How can I set the application logo on my Electron-Vue app?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31529772/19171888) your question?

Comment: Please use relative path (not static path)
icon : path.join(__dirname, 'xxxx')